# Check if email has a certain domain or not

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add a check to see if an email (string) is part of a specific domain in google scripts. For example, the domain would be "@company.com", so all emails with this would pass the check and emails without it won't

basically what I have is a way to retrieve the current user's email using:

```
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
```

Now I want to check this email for a specific domain/company 
Example: abc@companyname.com

so in this case it would be the "@companyname.com" part

I know there usually is a way to do this in other languages but how can I do this in apps script?

Comment: Please include a code snippet showing what you've attempted so far.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code. Show us what you got, or make an effort of your own and come back with it if it doesn't work.

Comment: If anything is unclear, reread [ask].

Comment: @LGSon Please see edit

Comment: @glhr please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function which uses a regular expression to match valid e-mails, and logs the result. Note that I'm using the `i` flag to do a case-insensitive search:

```
function emailCheck(email) {
  var regExp = new RegExp("[a-z0-9\.-_]*@companyname\.com$", "i");
  match = email.match(regExp);
  if(match)
    match = true;
  else
    match = false
  Logger.log(email + ' - ' + match);
  return match
}
```

The following inputs:

```
tests = ['ABC.345@companyNAME.com','no_no@goggle.com','ABC.345@companyNAME.com.edu']
for each (test in tests) {
    emailCheck(test);
}
```

Output:

```
ABC.345@companyNAME.com - true
no_no@goggle.com - false
ABC.345@companyNAME.com.edu - false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test an email by using this simple regular expression:

```
/@company\.com$/
```

And with JavaScript you can use this true/false test:

```
/@company\.com$/.test(email)
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const emailTest = email => /@company\.com$/.test(email);

['abc@company.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc.123@gmail.company.com', 'defg@company.com', 'abc.123@company.gmail.com']
  .forEach(email => console.log(email.padEnd(30), emailTest(email)))
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in apps script.